# Debugging Rails in Netbeans 6.9 suddenly stopped working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, debugging, netbeans

Yesterday I was perfectly able to debug a rails application using Netbeans 6.9.1 (just clicking on the Debug Main Project).

But now, suddenly when I try to debug I see the "Server Startup" at the bottom... but after 30 secs aprox. a message appears in the status bar saying "Cannot connect to web server, cannot show localhost:3000".

I'm using Windows 7 x64 (yes, I know I should be developing under linux, but I don't have the time to make the transition), Netbeans 6.9.1, Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 2.3.8 and the Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide).

I'm a MS/.NET guy trying to migrate to the wonderful world of OpenSource and RoR.... but it can't be to hard to debug.... I'm not asking too much I think =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, uninstalling and reinstalling fast-debug-ide gem solved the problem.